# How to store login session id in cookie in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies

I have the following piece of code where I am storing the login credentials of user in local storage along with his authority(whether he is admin or not).

```
.success(function (user) {
            localStorageService.set('localStorageUser', user.username);
            localStorageService.set('localStorageUserRole', user.authorities[0].authority);

            $rootScope.showMenu = true;
            $rootScope.user = user.username;

             if(localStorageService.get('localStorageUserRole') === 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
                 $rootScope.isAdmin = true;                  
             }
             else {
                 $rootScope.isAdmin = false;                     
             }                

            d.resolve();
        })
```

I want to know how I can store the user login session id in a cookie and also set an expiration date for the cookie in AngularJS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS have already provided a wrapper to work with cookies.

You can visit this page to know how to add the ngCookies plug-in to your project: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies

> First include angular-cookies.js in your HTML:
>
> You can
>   download this file from the following places:
>
> Google CDN e.g.
>
> //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-cookies.js
>
> Then load the module in your application by adding it as a dependent
>   module:
>
> angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']);
>
> With that you're ready to get
>   started!

The use of $cookie is very simple:

```
$cookies.put('user', user.username);
var username = $cookies.get('user');

//You can set the expired time with the third params
var today = new Date();
var expired = new Date(today);
expired.setDate(today.getDate() + 1); //Set expired date to tomorrow
$cookies.put('user', user.username, {expires : expired });
```

More about $cookies: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: Why do you create a `today` at all? Why not just set expired to `new Date();`?